# How to write SQL query without a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm looking to convert this table:

```
NAME    PROD    IS_PAID 
X       A       0   
X       B       1   
X       C       0   
..
```

To this, meaning if user paid for atleast one product then I would like to mark him as paid user for other products as well:

```
NAME    PROD    IS_PAID 
X       A       1   
X       B       1   
X       C       1   
..
```

Is there a way to do that without doing any joins?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists` to do this.

```
select name,prod,
case when exists (select 1 from t where name=t1.name and is_paid=1) then 1 else 0 end is_paid
from t t1
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe the `EXISTS` clause will be rewritten to a JOIN. I'll give it a try anyways.

Comment: @user2727704 There's no way to do relationships in MySQL without something that's logically equivalent to a join.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use variables:

```
  select t.*, 
         (@ip = if(@n = name, @ip,
                   if(@n := name, @ip := is_paid, @ip := is_paid)
                  )
         ) as new_is_paid
  from t cross join
       (select @n := '', @ip := 0) params
  order by name, is_paid desc;
```